# Testing a string for specific ASCII characters using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to make sure that a string does not have any weird [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters.

I'm trying to use character classes and negation.

```
 var tester =/[^\x00-\x001F\x007\x080-\xA1]+/i;
```

So: no ASCII characters between 00-1F, 07; or 80-A1 should be present. Everything else should be fine.

I am coming back to regular expressions after a long time away... The regular expression is NOT working. I want a string like "hello" to pass and a string like "†ack!" to fail. Or, is my [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)/[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) code wrong?

The code:

```
var tester2 = /^[^\x00-\x1f\x80-\xa1]+$/;
    $('#testButton').click(function(){
        var text1 = $('#ackInput').val();
        console.log("text: " + text1);
        var allowed  = tester2.test(text1);
        var feedback = "allowed?" + allowed;
        console.log(feedback);
        $('#errorTestInputAllowedChars').text(feedback);
    });
```

An entry on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is at http://jsfiddle.net/jillrenee42/WE79e/2/.

Comment: edited to make it clearer

Comment: @hwnd or `/^[ -~]+$/`

Comment: international printed chars are desired, hence the /^[ -~]+$/ does not fill business requirements

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle that shows the fixed regex working.](http://jsfiddle.net/j33TK/)

Comment: The "dagger" symbol that you get from &dagger; is not 86 hex; it's a Unicode character (&#8224;)

Comment: @Pointy:  how did you figure that out?  (that's it not 86 hex and is the unicode that is way outside the range?)  thanks.

Comment: I looked it up [using this reference](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html).  I don't have any idea why the HTML entities were set up that way.  The characters in the upper part of 8-bit encodings are kind-of not well-standardized I think; real "ASCII" is only a 7-bit code.

Comment: so this is not just a lesson in regex; but in unicode: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361579/are-unicode-and-ascii-characters-the-same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the **whole string** matches:

```
var tester = /^[^\x00-\x001F\x007\x080-\xA1]+$/i;
```

That `\x` notation doesn't seem correct to me, and this works when I try it:

```
var tester = /^[^\u0000-\u001F\u0080-\u00A1]+$/i;
```

Comment: I tried that.  then the string "hello" is false (not true as it should be)

Comment: I updated the fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/jillrenee42/WE79e/1/ and it now passes EVERYTHING; including the †ack string

Comment: @JillRenee you did not update the fiddle correctly; your regular expression is still invalid, and it doesn't include the `^` and `$` at the start and end.

Comment: how are you testing it?  this is very frustrating; so far nothing is working for me.

Comment: @JillRenee The "dagger" symbol has a character code that falls far outside the ranges you are disallowing.

Comment: @JillRenee in other words, the dagger symbol *should* pass the test.

Comment: but the "dagger" is 86 in Hex; which would be between 80-a1 . see: 
http://www.ascii-code.com/ .  There is something here I am not getting/understanding.

Comment: changed the regex to: var tester = /^[^\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u00A1]+$/i;     

and I'm using that one.@Pointy thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript hexcodes are 2 digit codes so following will work for you:

```
/^[^\x00-\x1F\x07\x80-\xFF]+$/
```

[**Javascript Regex Reference**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)

Comment: Yes with `\u` it will take 4 digit `\uhhhh` form

Answer (score 0):

Your hex encodings of your desired ranges are incorrect. You want this instead

```
[^\x00-\x1f\x80-\xa1]
```

Note I left out `\x07` because that's already in the range of `\x00-\x1f`

---

**EDIT**

As Pointy points out, you will need to negate the entire string.

Comment: still not working.  is it a problem with my javascript?