# scanner in while loop

Tags: java, c#, if-statement, while-loop

```
private int scanner = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
public void Play()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (scanner > theNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your number is too big");
                } else 
                if (scanner < theNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your number is too big");
                }  else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you got it");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

this is a simple game where I need to iterate thr same number through the set of `if` statements. in Java they use

```
int x;

x = scn.nextInt();
```

**What can I use in C#?** There is no scanner.

[C# equivalent to Java's scn.nextInt( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856969/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-scn-nextint) this post doesn't explain how to make a scanner in C#. It only explains how to parse user's input so that make it Integer only

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` can raise an exception depending on what does the user input. `Int32.TryParse` is a better choice.

Comment: [C# equivalent to Java's scn.nextInt( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856969/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-scn-nextint)

Comment: If you really need the Java like Scanner, you can port the https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java . The C# conversion should be really straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's *extract a method* (`ReadInteger`) for it. Please, note, that we use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` since user input is not necessary a *valid integer*

```
 private static int ReadInteger(String title = null) 
 {
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
         Console.WriteLine(title);

     while (true) 
     {
         if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
             return result;

         Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the input is not a valid integer, try again");
      } 
 }
```

Then we can use it:

```
    public void Play()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // We should re-read value after each attempt
            int value = ReadInteger();

            if (value > theNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("your number is too big");
            } 
            else if (value < theNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("your number is too big");
            }  
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you got it");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. this is a part I was struggling with: `if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
             return result;`

Comment: @feedthemachine: I see; unlike c#, Java doesn't have `ref` and `out` parameters